# Alternative to MySQL subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have 3 tables with columns:

### **products**

id - name

### **shop_previews** (box with products)

id - name - publish(datetime)

### **products_shop_previews**

id_product - id_shop_preview

I need to get latest one shop_preview with products. It is possible with subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM shop_previews WHERE publish < NOW() ORDER BY publish DESC LIMIT 1) as latest
INNER JOIN products_shop_previews psp ON psp.shop_preview_id = latest.id
INNER JOIN products p ON p.id = psp.product_id
```

But, is it possible without subquery?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand exactly what you want to do but i think that you need subquery here. If the tables are joined by the fields you can select it like this:

```
SELECT 
    *, psp.publish as latest
FROM 
    shop_previews
INNER JOIN 
    products_shop_previews psp ON psp.shop_preview_id = latest.id
INNER JOIN 
    products p ON p.id = psp.product_id
WHERE 
    psp.publish < NOW() 
ORDER BY 
    psp.publish
```

This should work but I haven't tested it.

Comment: This query gets all dates, but I need only one latest publish date.

Comment: Have you tried to add: LIMIT 1 in it? If you order it by publish and get only one result it will be the one you want.

Comment: When I add LIMIT 1 and shop_previews have more products I will get only   one product. I need all products in shop preview box from latest date.